# Why does my unity music lens not play anything?

Tags: 12.04, unity, music

My music lens in 12.04 unity will access my entire library, but if I click on anything to play it, Rhythmbox opens and does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have installed Ubuntu Restricted Extras to enable multimedia support?

If not open Ubuntu Software Centre and search for `ubuntu restricted extras`.
Then click install (where it says remove in screenshot below).
You may need to use Tab & Enter to accept the license when it asks.

[image: restricted extras in software centre]

Comment: Yup, one of my first packages installed.  It's odd, just seems that unity and rhythmbox aren't talking to each other.

Comment: Very odd, I have the opposite problem, the music lens only opens files with rhythm box even though my default is VLC. Sorry not to be of more help.